# Wordpress mobile pages

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

Is there a way in wordpress that I can create custom page templates for a mobile version, I mean something like when it detects that is a mobile to load `mobile_header.php` or is there a better way, I can't do this only from css I also need to use some custom page templates.

Thanks!

Comment: There are plugins made especially for this; why not use them?

Comment: Can you recommend me one? But I need the ability to customize it change templates and so on.

Comment: A better place to ask this would be wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create a new theme which is a mobile template specifically. You can then put this code into your functions.php file and it will use the mobile template instead.

```
add_filter('option_template', 'mobileTheme');
add_filter('template', 'mobileTheme');
add_filter('option_template', 'mobileTheme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'mobileTheme');

function mobileTheme($theme) {
    global $mobile;

    if($mobile)
        $theme = 'mobile_theme';

    return $theme;
}
```

You'd have to work out if it is a mobile phone useragent or not though.

Comment: Hmmm great adive Sir, Thanks a lot, I will probably go this way, and if I detected it that the useragen is mobile how can I switch the theme? I need to apply those add_filtes in the if statement to change the theme.

Comment: The code above switches the theme. If `$mobile` is `true` then it will set the theme to `mobile_theme` rather than the theme you've chosen in your settings. e.g. make a new theme and change the name of that theme to `mobile_theme` (or change `$theme = 'mobile_theme';` in the code above to `$theme = 'NAME OF YOUR MOBILE THEME HERE';`). To detect whether the user is browsing on a mobile you can use this code: http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/screenshots/ I guess is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

How about WPTouch? It is a WP plugin.